# Get http request on server side works but not display on client side [Angular Universal(universal cli)]

Tags: angular, angular-universal, universal-cli

I have request like this:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {isNode} from 'angular2-universal';


@Component({
    selector: 'app-todo',
    templateUrl: './todo.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./todo.component.css']
})
export class TodoComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private http: Http) {}
    private todo: any;

    ngOnInit() {
        if(isNode) {
            this.http
            .get('http://api.pushsc.com/api/v1/code/show/589ceab40a58d602a0b99d10')
            .map((response: Response) => response.json())
            .subscribe(data => {
                console.log(data);
                this.todo = data;
            })
            error => {
                console.log(error);
            };
        }

    }

}
```

In console I get response from API which mean http from server works... But poroblem is on client even if I remove `isNode` content from http not render as it should... What can be a problem?

Comment: *content from http not render as it should*... what does that mean? How does it render currently and how do you expect it should render?

Comment: I'm faced with the same issue, did you solve it ?

Comment: Can u update to angular4? look this

* https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/694#issuecomment-297012203

This should be the guide

https://github.com/angular/universal/blob/master/UPGRADE-GUIDE.md

Answer (score 0):

You need to install and enable preboot https://github.com/angular/preboot for run code on client side.

Answer (score -1):

From the source code of angular2-universal from this **[link](https://github.com/angular/universal/blob/master/modules/universal/src/node/env.ts)**

By default the value assigned to the `isNode` is true and so your http call fails if it is not available.

Comment: Please read question to the end. Even if I remove `isNode` it will not work client side just not picking up http request from server side.